# Exhaustive proof: why is proof by cases joined by disjunction?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

In a proof by cases, to show an implication, $$(p_{1}\lor p_{2}\lor ... p_{n})\rightarrow q$$

**Why are we using dijsunction instead of conjunction?** Conjunction seems to be stronger since if one of $p\in (p_{1},...,p_{n})$ is False. The disjunction $(p_{1}\lor p_{2}\lor ... p_{n})$ would still be True. With conjunction, it would be False.

Comment: The answer to your question is that it obviously depends on the situation. Also you mean 'could' not 'would'.

Comment: Conjunction requires all of the $p_i$ to be true. The disjunction only requires one of them to be true. It is certainly true that if all of them are true then one of them is true but it may be the case that not all of them are true and $q$ must still be true.

Comment: Cases are often mutually exclusive. Would conjunction make any sense?

Comment: @JohnDouma but then that means that not all the cases have been shown to be True. Are we not supposed to show True for every proposition?

Comment: @mohammed You need to show that the proposition is true for all combinations of the $p_i$ where at least one of the $p_i$ is true. The case where all the $p_i$ are true is one case.

Comment: @JohnDouma Oh, I see. Clear. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of **proof by cases** is that :

1. When do know that *at least one* among a set of cases must hold, though not which one.
2. And we can derive the *same* conclusion if *each* case were true.
3. Then we may therefore infer that that conclusion holds.

$$(p_1\vee p_2\vee\cdots\vee p_n)~\land~(p_1\to c)~\land~(p_2\to c)~\land~\cdots~\land~(p_n\to c)  \vdash c$$

---

> **Why are we using dijsunction instead of conjunction?** Conjunction seems to be stronger since if one of p∈(p1,...,pn) is False, the disjunction (p1∨p2∨...pn) would still be True. With conjunction, it would be False.

That *is* why we prefer the antecedent to be weaker.

When given that *all* the disjuncts will entail the conclusion, then *to derive that conclusion*, we would only need to prove that **at least one** among the disjuncts holds (even if we do not know *which* one does).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're interpreting what it's implying incorrectly.

$(p_1 \lor p_2 \lor \ldots \lor p_n) \implies q$ means "as long as at least one of the propositions $p_i$ is true, we can conclude that $q$ is true". That means that this is equivalent to $(p_1 \implies q) \land (p_2 \implies q) \land \ldots (p_n \implies q)$.

Think about what it takes to falsify the statement, i.e. consider the converse:

$\lnot q \implies \lnot (p_1 \lor p_2 \lor \ldots \lor p_n)$

So $q$ being false means that $p_1 \lor \ldots \lor p_n$ is false, but the only time a disjunction is false is when *all* of its components are false, i.e. $\lnot p_1 \land \lnot p_2 \land \ldots \land \lnot p_n$.

By comparison, if you had $(p_1 \land p_2 \land \ldots \land p_n) \implies q$, that means you know that having *all* of the propositions being true lets you conclude that $q$ is also true. It tells you nothing about what happens if $p_1, p_2, p_4$ are true but $p_3$ is false.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental point in the method of proof by cases is that the list of cases, whatever they are, must be exhaustive.

Thus, we actually have two kinds of the method:

1. For all cases in the list $p_{1}, p_{2},\ldots, p_{n}$, the conclusion $q$ follows.
2. For at least one case in the list $p_{1}, p_{2},\ldots, p_{n}$, the conclusion $q$ follows.

For example, consider a set of integers $A=\{a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}, a_{4}\}$

The claim could be that all the integers in the set $A$ are multiples of . . .

Or, it could be that at least one of the integers in the set $A$ is a multiple of . . .

The conjunctive form expresses only the "for all cases" form.

The disjunctive form expresses both kinds, hence, it represents the general logical form of the method.

Comment: Clear. Could you comment on why/how the disjunction expresses the general form?

Comment: Nevermind, I think it is clear since case by case at least one $p_{n}$ can be true and others false. And, it also allows all $p\in \{p_{1},..., p_{n}\}$ to all be true

Comment: A point of caution: In many sources, disjunction elimination ($\lor$-E) in natural deduction is taken as a counterpart of proof by cases.  I think, however, that is an oversimplification. $\lor$-E does not reflect the full conceptual content of the mathematical practice of the method (notice that the conclusion is derived for each disjunct in $\lor$-E).